# Treeview control in ASP .net

Tags: javascript, treeview

I have a treeview control in my web application. I build this tree view dynamically.

Is there anyway to select a node and change the color of the selected node using javascript or any other method running in client side(i mean without post back).

i am using c# and asp.net to bulid my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT (To explain a little more on JQuery): 

[JQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) is a .js file containing JavaScript functions to make it easier to navigate a document, select DOM elements, create animations, handle events, and develop Ajax applications.

You can download JQuery.js file from [JQuery official website](http://jquery.com/), then reference to the JQuery.js file (like you reference to other .js file) before you call your first JQuery script, as followed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
```

Or alternatively, you can use the [JQuery.js file hosted by Google](http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/). This is what I did for my testing. Below is the complete code of my .aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TreeView.aspx.cs" Inherits="TreeView" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // You may specify partial version numbers, such as "1" or "1.3",
        //  with the same result. Doing so will automatically load the 
        //  latest version matching that partial revision pattern 
        //  (e.g. 1.3 would load 1.3.2 today and 1 would load 1.4.2).
        google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");

        google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
            // Place init code here instead of $(document).ready()

            //change cursor to hand when user mouseover tree nodes
            $(".TreeView1_0").mouseover(function() {
                $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
            });


            //unbold all nodes then bold the selected node to indicate it's selected
            $(".TreeView1_0").click(function() {
                $(".TreeView1_0").css('font-weight', 'normal');
                $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
        </asp:TreeView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow. Its really great. Thank you Lee. But i have one more doubt. i have a button on the form.and i just want to get the selected node value.its just an example-->  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value;
    }
but its gives an error like this -->Object reference not set to an instance of an object.Is there any way to solve this?. Thnks again

Comment: When you remove the hyperlinks by setting select action to 'none', the page will not do postback when you click on the node. Hence, no data is posting to server, server will not know what is the current selected node. You have to workaround your code further like putting hidden field in your page. I would rather advise you to use Ajax UpdatePanel in this case instead of doing so many workarounds :)

Comment: Thank you.Now i am searching on Hidden fields :D. u help me a lot

Comment: i have one more doubt i added a HiddenField1 to my form. How can i assign selected node index to this hidden field on click function

Answer (score 0):

2 ways I can thought of to implement this:

1. Wrap your treeview with Ajax UpdatePanel. This is more straight forward.
2. Remove hyperlink from tree nodes using recursive function, then bind client side click event to all the nodes using JQuery.

More details for method 2 as followed..

Place treeview control onto aspx page

`<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
</asp:TreeView>`

Add dummy nodes and call recursive function to remove hyperlinks

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //add dummy nodes
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode() { Value = "1", Text = "One" });
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode() { Value = "2", Text = "Two" });
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode() { Value = "3", Text = "Three" });

        //call recursive function to remove hyperlinks
        RemoveHyperLinks(TreeView1, TreeView1.Nodes);
    }
}
```

Implement the recursive function

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView RemoveHyperLinks(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView treeView, TreeNodeCollection treeNodes)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in treeNodes)
    {
        node.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;//here the link is removed
        if (node.ChildNodes != null && node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
        {
            treeView = RemoveHyperLinks(treeView, node.ChildNodes);
        }
    }
    return treeView;
}
```

Place this JQuery code on aspx page

```
//change cursor to hand when user mouseover tree nodes
$(".TreeView1_0").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
});


//unbold all nodes then bold the selected node to indicate it's selected
$(".TreeView1_0").click(function() {
    $(".TreeView1_0").css('font-weight', 'normal');
    $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
});
```

Comment: Thank you lee. Everything working fine except java code. 

   
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(".TreeView1_0").mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        });
        

        $(".TreeView1_0").click(function() {
            $(".TreeView1_0").css('font-weight', 'normal');
            $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
        });
</script>


is the way i placed the code is  correct?
the mouseover and click function not firing. i can remove the hyperlink recursively

Comment: Did you reference to jquery.js?

Comment: Another possibility is the css class of your tree node. I am hardcoding the class name. <span class="TreeView1_0" id="TreeView1t0">One</span>. Yours might not be "TreeView1_0".

Comment: what you mean by the jqyery.js reference.?? i just placed the same  java code you given within a script tag in aspx head section.i am a beginner. thaks in advance

Comment: I have added explanation about JQuery below.